# Android Application : Opening specific content by passing parameter in outlook app through different application

Tags: android, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an application supporting some additional filters that syncs with the cloud storage and  fetches some email through that. Now I want to open specific emails in outlook app. Suppose I click on one email thread then that particular should popup in outlook app. I know how to open full application but how should I pass parameters with email so that It opens up in Outlook.
(Also I have done this similar thing in outlook desktop client, but don't know how to do this in Android.)

Any help would be appreciated.